# Oracle SQL - LEFT OUTER JOIN not returning rows with null values

Tags: join, count, outer-join

I've read numerous posts about this, and am unable to determine how my query differs from the ones whose questions were answered. Any help would be sincerely appreciated. Here is my query:

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE, COUNT(B.DEPENDENT)
FROM TABLE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE B ON A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID
WHERE A.EMP_ID = '12345'
  AND B.DEP_RELATION = 'CHILD'
GROUP BY A.EMP_ID
```

I entered my own EMP_ID to check the query. I have no children, and the query is returning no results. I want it to show my EMP_ID and (null).

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is checking table B.

Try removing `AND B.DEP_RELATION = 'CHILD'` and see if you get the results you want

Comment: It shows me as having 1 DEPENDENT, which is my spouse.

Comment: @glennsnoise is this not what you expect? It is difficult to figure out the desired results without knowing the full table structures

Comment: I have zero children. I am looking for the query to return (null). Right now, when I specify B.DEP_RELATION = 'CHILD', I get nothing.

Comment: I think I have figured out your issue. You want to only count the Child dependents not all of them in table B.  Instead of checking `B.DEP_RELATION` in the `WHERE` clause move it to the `JOIN` clause. Right now the query is selecting rows where this is a child. What you want to is join those rows and then select all rows in A

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Problem solved. Now, any idea on how to have two left outer joins? I created two instances of TABLE B, one specifying 'CHILD' and the other specifying 'SPOUSE.' When I run the query, the first left outer join seems to overwrite the data. For instance, I've got employees showing up with 4 CHILD and 4 SPOUSE.

Comment: @glennoise Without knowing your database structure it's difficult to know exactly what your issue is, but it sounds like a problem with the select clause. It may be necessary to use AS clauses to avoid overlap

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to move my B.DEP_RELATION = 'CHILD' line above the WHERE clause. Thank you.